# How can I make these two divs with text responsive?

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design

I have two divs like this :

```
    <div id="splash-container">
     <video id="splash-video" preload autoplay loop muted>
        <source src="videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
     </video>
     <div id="splash-message">MAYUR BHADRACANT</div>
     <div id="splash-submessage">ONLINE PROFILE</div>
   </div>
```

I want the splash-message to show on top of the splash-submessage like this:
http://prntscr.com/bcxu1r

But when I resize the browser: this happens:
http://prntscr.com/bcxuec

My current css right now is:

```
    #splash-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100vw;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}

    #splash-message {
position: absolute;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 1;
color:white;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: 7px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 35.5px;
top:40vh;
}


#splash-submessage {
position: absolute;
color: white;
z-index: 1;
font-weight: 300;
letter-spacing: 7px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 22px;
top:50vh;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With `Flexbox` you can center `message` and `submessage` and you can use `position: absolute` on **video** to remove it from elements flow and then use `transform: translate()` to center it.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#splash-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
video {
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="splash-container">
  <video id="splash-video" preload autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="videos/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
  </video>
  <div id="splash-message">MAYUR BHADRACANT</div>
  <div id="splash-submessage">ONLINE PROFILE</div>
</div>
```